Two Gimp icons are in ShowApps list
After a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04, I've installed Gimp, than other apps, and finally the Gmic's, which is a Gimp plugin.
Later on, I realized two Gimp icons (apps) are visible in snap (ShowApp), one of them with Gmic's plugin, and the another one is without the Gmic's.
How can I remove the one which is without the plugin?

